# How to handle RVEST:::request_POST in today's RVEST package?

Tags: rvest

rvest's internal function rvest:::request_POST is deprecated / not working anymore. How should the request be handled today?

I would like to perform a POST using the session collected previously and this function used to be my go-to. Now that it is deprecated, can someone please help me.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You might be able to use html_form_submit. See here: https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/issues/341 
Depending on what exactly you need from the previous session to send a valid POST request, you can probably get cookies, configs and handles from the session and manually pass it on to the POST request. Maybe you could provide the specific example?

Comment: I'm trying to simulate "addtocart" action from this page in RVEST
https://www.grainger.com/product/PIP-Gloves-395N20

I'm unable to use the html_form initially to get the form to fill out the values and submit